# Angular Data Table: The "angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I almost tried all the options to implement Angular Data Table by following the below resources:

- https://github.com/ggmod/angular-2-data-table,
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable,
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-4-data-table
- https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table

Every time I run `npm install` after following the instructions given in the resources, I am getting `The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed`. Also I tried these possible solutions

- [Angular2 CLI error "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925690/angular2-cli-error-angular-compiler-cli-package-was-not-properly-installed)
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5654
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5790

Even though these resources helped others to resolve their issue, My error is still persisting.i.e every time I am getting the same error `The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.`

Here are the couple of things I tried

1. Remove `node_modules` and run `npm install`
2. Installing latest version of `typescript 2.2` and above
3. Re-install cli `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`
4. Downgrading Angular-CLI version
5. I also followed [How to use angular2-data-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596304/) and I agree with the author of the post that there are no good/clear tutorials for angular 2 data tables using angular CLI.

My Code snippets are as shown below

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": 
"@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"angular-datatables": "^4.1.1",
"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^9.3.1",
"datatables.net": "^1.10.15"

"devDependencies": 
"@angular/cli": "^1.2.6",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.3",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
"@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.5",
"typescript": "~2.3.3"
```

**.angularcli.json**

```
"index": "index.html",
"main": "main.ts",
"polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
"test": "test.ts",
"tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
"testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json"
```

**Version Details**

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.6
node: 8.0.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.2.3
@angular/common: 4.2.3
@angular/compiler: 4.2.3
@angular/core: 4.2.6
@angular/forms: 4.2.3
@angular/http: 4.2.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.3
@angular/router: 4.2.3
@angular/cli: 1.2.6
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.3
@angular/language-service: 4.2.3
```

Any inputs and suggestions will be very helpful. Thank You.

Comment: Do you have permission restrictions on your PC? Also what happens when you run `ng -v`?

Comment: I don't have any restrictions.                                                                                      ng -v   gives me version details                                               @angular/cli: 1.2.6
node: 8.0.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.2.3
@angular/common: 4.2.3
@angular/compiler: 4.2.3
@angular/core: 4.2.6
@angular/forms: 4.2.3
@angular/http: 4.2.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.3
@angular/router: 4.2.3
@angular/cli: 1.2.6
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.3
@angular/language-service: 4.2.3

Comment: Can you `ng new my-app`, `npm install`, `npm start`. without getting any errors? if there will be no errors so far what happend if you do say `npm install @swimlane/ngx-datatable --save` ?

Comment: I tried it. I am getting the same error